# How to highlight selected item in Longlistselector?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have searching and find the solutions in stackoverflow and other solutions.  I got the link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444

Here i got the solution is that it shows the selected item highlighted is for user control.

I have only textblock inside the longlistselector.  How to highlight the selected item in longlistselector.  I didnot use usercontrol in my page.

Here is code:

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}" x:Name="MyLongListSelector2" Margin="0,304,-12,0" SelectionChanged="MyLongListSelector2_SelectionChanged" >
 <DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock x:Name="txtblock"/>
 </DataTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Any idea or link should help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the solution depends on how you are implementing the style. it would be helpful if you share the xaml longlistselector and its style if you are using styles)

Comment: Style is same as in above link

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in your selection changed event?

```
 List<TextBlock> userControlList = new List<TextBlock>(); 
        GetItemsRecursive<TextBlock>(MyLongListSelector1, ref userControlList);


        // Selected. 
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (TextBlock txtBlock in userControlList)
            {
                if (e.AddedItems[0].Equals(txtBlock.DataContext))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(txtBlock, "Selected", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It got error on VisualStateManager.GoToState(txtBlock,"selected",true); and error is "The best overloaded method match .... has some invalid arguments....